# connectedness and disconnectednes of special functions space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $t_0 \in [0,1]$ fixed point. show that:

1. $ \{ f | f(t_0) \neq 0 \} \subset C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ is disconnected
2. $ \{ f | f(t_0) \neq 0 \} \subset C([0,1],\mathbb{C})$ is path-connected

where C(X,Y) stands for all continuous functions from X to Y

Thanks

Comment: the sup metrics assumed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first, take $A_1=\{f \mid f(t_0) >0\}$ and $A_2=\{g \mid g(t_0) <0\}$ and prove this is a separation.

For the second, I give you a hint: you can "go around" $0$ :).

Comment: Take a point $f \in A_1$. We must show that $f$ is an interior point. For that, just take any $0< \epsilon< f(t_0)$ and use the ball of radius $f(t_0)-\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for the first.
For the seconed: I assume I should "go around 0 through the imaginary part", but I can't figure out (yet) how to build the path

Answer (score 0):

Define $F_x:(C[0,1],\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}, F_x(f) := f(x). $

$F_x$ are bounded linear functionals (we are using the sup metric, so $|F_x(f)| \leq \sup|f| = |f|$), so in particular it is continuous.

So, the sets $A := \{f : f(x) < 0 \}  B:= \{f : f(x) > 0 \}$ are disjoint.

And further $F_x^{-1}(-\infty,0) = A, F_x^{-1}(0,\infty) = B $ are open, so we are done with the first part.

Second part.

Let $f,g \in A := \{l \in (C[0,1],\mathbb{C}) : l(z) \neq 0 \}$.

Let $K = \{q \in (C[0,1],\mathbb{C}) : \forall z \in [0,1] q(z) = k, k \neq 0  \}$.

We know that $K \cong \mathbb{C} \backslash\ \{ 0\}$. So they are both path connected.

Let $a := f(z), b := g(z)$.

Let $h \in A $

Define $H_l : [0,1] \to (C[0,1],\mathbb{C})$ where $ H_l(t)(\omega) := at + (1-t)l(\omega) $

As $h \in A:$

$H_h(t)(z) = at + (1-t)h(z) = at + (1-t)a = a \neq 0.$

So $f,g$ are path connected to $K$ in $A$, and $K$ is path connected, so $A$ is path connected QED

Comment: Your $H_t $ might hit $0 \in \mathbb C$.

Comment: @JohnMa  Ah, $h$ should be in $A$. The second to last line assumes this.

Comment: The path $H_h(t)(z) = at +(1-t)h(z)$ is a path in $C([0,1], \mathbb C)$ joining $h$ to the constant function $a$. But this path might not be in $A$. For example, if $h(z) = e^{i2\pi z}$, then for all $a$, $H_h$ will hit $0 \in \mathbb C$ for some $t$.

Comment: @JohnMa but I said that $h(z) =a$, we only need to avoid 0 for $H_h(t)(z)$, the function space does not have to avoid zero entirely, only for values of the functions at a particular fixed point. Look at the algebra: We know that $h(z) = a,$ so $H_h(t)(z) = at+(1-t)a = at +a -at = a \neq 0$.

Comment: Um, you are right. I would suggest you to change the notation: The $z$ in the definition of $A$ is fixed (I assume that corresponds to $t_0$?) and that $z$ in the definition in $K$ is for all.